# elasticsearch error kubernetes.labels.app

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, label, filebeat

I have a customized kubernetes, I want to analyze all the logs in it, I found the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/running-on-kubernetes.html#running-on-kubernetes)
set everything up according to the documentation, my filebeat-kubernetes.yaml configuration files turned out to be

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.config:
      inputs:
        # Mounted `filebeat-inputs` configmap:
        path: ${path.config}/inputs.d/*.yml
        # Reload inputs configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false
      modules:
        path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
        # Reload module configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false

# To enable hints based autodiscover, remove `filebeat.config.inputs` configuration and uncomment this:
#filebeat.autodiscover:
#  providers:
#    - type: kubernetes
#      hints.enabled: true

processors:
  - add_cloud_metadata:

cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts:['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:my_ip}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   name: filebeat-inputs
   namespace: kube-system
   labels:
     k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - type: docker
  containers.ids:
  - "*"
  processors:
    - add_kubernetes_metadata:
        in_cluster: true
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
  spec:
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          k8s-app: filebeat
  spec:
    serviceAccountName: filebeat
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    containers:
    - name: filebeat
      image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.4.2
      args: [
        "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
        "-e",
      ]
      env:
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
      value: my_ip
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
      value: "9200"
    - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
      value:
    - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
      value:
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
      # If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
      #privileged: true
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 200Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 100Mi
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config
      mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
      readOnly: true
      subPath: filebeat.yml
    - name: inputs
      mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/inputs.d
      readOnly: true
    - name: data
      mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
    - name: varlibdockercontainers
      mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
      readOnly: true
    volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        defaultMode: 0600
        name: filebeat-config
    - name: varlibdockercontainers
      hostPath:
        path: /var/lib/docker/containers
    - name: inputs
      configMap:
        defaultMode: 0600
        name: filebeat-inputs
    # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
    - name: data
      hostPath:
        path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
 kind: ClusterRole
 name: filebeat
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
 - apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
   resources:
   - namespaces
   - pods
   verbs:
   - get
   - watch
   - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
---
```

run filebeat-kubernetes.yaml

```
kubectl create -f filebeat-kubernetes.yaml
```

I get indexes in elasticsearch

```
 yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.09 9A42qYPRSem4Z6ZBZQ1P7A 5 1     1129 0 457.3kb 457.3kb                                                    
 yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.11 6-8oKQ_RQBCx9D71kHhSiQ 5 1       32 0  56.4kb  56.4kb                                                    
 yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.10 Wc5xG55KRMWJXqJjfhBbUA 5 1    36826 0  29.8mb  29.8mb
```

but I have such errors in the elasticsearch logs

```
 [DEBUG][o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction] [filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.11] 
 [3] failed to execute bulk item (index) BulkShardRequest [[filebeat- 
 6.4.2-2018.10.11][3]] containing [8] requests
 org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [kubernetes.labels.app]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:302) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:481) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:501) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:380) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:478) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:501) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:380) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:478) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
...
```

kubernetes version and elasticsearch version

```
kubectl version                                                                                                 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.3", GitCommit:"a4529464e4629c21224b3d52edfe0ea91b072862", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-09T17:53:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.3", GitCommit:"a4529464e4629c21224b3d52edfe0ea91b072862", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-09T17:53:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

curl -XGET localhost:9200
{
   "name" : "el3",
   "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
   "cluster_uuid" : "hmmQcpMdSYCM8P3i9gOENw",
   "version" : {
     "number" : "6.4.2",
     "build_flavor" : "default",
     "build_type" : "deb",
     "build_hash" : "04711c2",
     "build_date" : "2018-09-26T13:34:09.098244Z",
     "build_snapshot" : false,
     "lucene_version" : "7.4.0",
     "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
     "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
   },
   "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

how to fix error failed to parse [kubernetes.labels.app]? or how can i remove filebeat - label from config?

**Update**

I added filebeat index template in elasticsearch, my file file-index-template.json

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        { 
          "template1": {
            "mapping": {
              "doc_values": true,
              "ignore_above": 1024,
              "index": "false",
              "type": "{dynamic_type}"
            },
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": "true"
        },
        "offset": {
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": "true"
        },
        "geoip": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
  },
  "template": "filebeat-*"
}
```

added template in elasticsearch

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/filebeat?pretty' -d@filebeat.json
```

check template

```
curl localhost:9200/_template/filebeat
{"filebeat":{"order":0,"index_patterns":["filebeat-*"],"settings":{"index":{"refresh_interval":"5s"}},"mappings":{"_default_":{"dynamic_templates":[{"template1":{"mapping":{"doc_values":true,"ignore_above":1024,"index":"false","type":"{dynamic_type}"},"match":"*"}}],"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date"},"message":{"type":"text","index":"true"},"offset":{"type":"long","doc_values":"true"},"geoip":{"type":"object","dynamic":true,"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point"}}}}}},"aliases":{}}}
```

check index

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.17 c9EmKOQ9T7W_pl9tDRDycQ 5 1 13719988 0  13.8gb  13.8gb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.14 daA_KAT_TYeL5Fn3SrT2Pw 5 1    56400 0  10.5mb  10.5mb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.16 70uY3kooTjWRNaFCky24jQ 5 1   277731 0  69.3mb  69.3mb
green  open .kibana                   DgMyQx7QSK659uBo1CccJQ 1 0        3 0  34.3kb  34.3kb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.13 LsC4soOYSEqY3vwv-HOcjg 5 1   135921 0  19.1mb  19.1mb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.15 hKNvyDl9SFSgw3nEU3faKg 5 1    72960 0  18.7mb  18.7mb
```

but still I see in the elasticsearch logs

```
[DEBUG][o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction] [filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.17][4] failed to execute bulk item (index) BulkShardRequest [[filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.17][4]] containing [13] requests
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [kubernetes.labels.app]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:302) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:481) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:501) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:380) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:478) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:501) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:380) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:478) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:501) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:380) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.internalParseDocument(DocumentParser.java:95) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:263) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:725) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyIndexOperation(IndexShard.java:702) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyIndexOperationOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:682) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.lambda$executeIndexRequestOnPrimary$2(TransportShardBulkAction.java:560) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
...
```

**Update 2**

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.25 0RCTMniqQyucD530dz_eOQ 5 1  511 0 491.1kb 491.1kb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.27 64b5ThH1TauvwMIo_ueTIg 5 1  487 0 479.4kb 479.4kb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.28 Lf4UzVzESIGfGvx7VsRzFQ 5 1  283 0 357.4kb 357.4kb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.24 fCUmzy2UQSy9lsNOMWmkEQ 5 1 2866 0   1.8mb   1.8mb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.26 t3rPwBS4TYOhJWjtFRYk6g 5 1  323 0 428.9kb 428.9kb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22 -Rq7SbeqS_yNX3I4lwsGRg 5 1   92 0 173.2kb 173.2kb
yellow open filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.29 yAje-vFhQqmavxSO7tlDGA 5 1 4810 0   8.5mb   8.5mb
```

Check elasticksearch

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty'
{
  "took" : 33,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 35,
    "successful" : 35,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 67309,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "-m0iwGYBP2-nX77s4y_g",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:36.393Z",
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:36.393 [INFO][92] int_dataplane.go 747: Finished applying updates to dataplane. msecToApply=92.064514",
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"
          },
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"
          },
"beat" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 630130,   
          "stream" : "stdout"  
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "_m0iwGYBP2-nX77s4y_g",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:38.159Z",
          "beat" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2"
          },
          "offset" : 630467,   
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:38.158 [INFO][92] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}",
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
"input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "n20iwGYBP2-nX77s5jGM",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:41.172Z",
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 631205,   
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:41.172 [INFO][92] table.go 438: Loading current iptables state and checking it is correct. ipVersion=0x4 table=\"raw\"",
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "beat" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
}
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "WG0iwGYBP2-nX77s6DIH",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:45.710Z",
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 632166,   
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:45.710 [INFO][92] ipsets.go 222: Asked to resync with the dataplane on next update. family=\"inet\"",
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "beat" : {
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2",
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "Wm0iwGYBP2-nX77s6DIH",
"_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:45.710Z",
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "beat" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 632353,   
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:45.710 [INFO][92] ipsets.go 253: Resyncing ipsets with dataplane. family=\"inet\"",
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "XG0iwGYBP2-nX77s6DIH",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:45.711Z",
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"
},
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "beat" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:45.711 [INFO][92] ipsets.go 295: Finished resync family=\"inet\" numInconsistenciesFound=0 resyncDuration=876.908µs",
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 632522
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "QG0iwGYBP2-nX77s6TNr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:45.711Z",
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 632726,   
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:45.711 [INFO][92] int_dataplane.go 747: Finished applying updates to dataplane. msecToApply=1.061403",
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "input" : {
"type" : "docker"  
          },
          "beat" : {
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2",
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1W0iwGYBP2-nX77s8zc2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:32:58.158Z",
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:32:58.158 [INFO][92] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}",
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 634199,   
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "beat" : {
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2",
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "host" : {
"name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "stream" : "stdout"  
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "-G0iwGYBP2-nX77s8zc2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:33:00.168Z",
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:33:00.167 [INFO][92] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}",
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log",
          "offset" : 634391,   
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "beat" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.22",
"_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "yW0iwGYBP2-nX77s_j2e",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-10-22T07:33:18.158Z",
          "offset" : 636780,   
          "stream" : "stdout", 
          "message" : "2018-10-22 07:33:18.158 [INFO][92] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}",
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "input" : {
            "type" : "docker"  
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc"
          },
          "beat" : {
            "name" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "hostname" : "filebeat-6p7rc",
            "version" : "6.4.2"
          },
          "source" : "/var/lib/docker/containers/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659/02ed5c70d5341a7d3f15fecbb24dd94bc43d850fc4fd6c609a771d487518d659-json.log"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share any information about cluster running environment?

Comment: what information interests?

Comment: Kubernetes cluster version and ElasticSearch version: `curl -XGET localhost:9200`

Comment: I added the information of the main task, please see

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you haven't set up an index template for [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html) fields, which should be parsed to `Elasticsearch` for further processing. You can find useful information in this [Article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04#load-filebeat-index-template-in-elasticsearch) about implementing the `Filebeat` index template on your cluster.

In addition, there was a similar issue reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-fluentd-kubernetes/issues/9) about parsing `kubernetes.labels` using `Logstash` event collector.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a little to my answer, according to your answers, but still, until I get an error

Comment: Check `Elasticsearch` whether it receives any data from `Filebeat` agent: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty'`.

Comment: look please, I answered in the first post - update 2

Comment: I would suggest to look at [Filebeat discussion 
 forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/beats/filebeat) and search there for any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a conflict between metadata labels,
The simplest way to handle it is to add "skip_labels" to your collector.